# how can I retrieve the values of an array between 2 markers in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of values, all strings. There are also 2 "marker" entries in the array, that signify what the values that follow are. Basically it's set up like so:

`$array['1','2','3','A','5','6','7','B','8','9']`

I need to retrieve the array indices *after* **A**, but *before* **B**. So, in this example, the indices of 5, 6, and 7.

I was thinking about doing this with a forloop and some iterative if statements.. But I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated :)

EDIT: also worth noting that A and B are not always at the same position in the array; some users will have more data between A and B than others, some won't have A and B at all. But if A is present, I need to get the values following it. If A and B are present they will also always have the same value (A and B).

EDIT2: This is what I'm currently trying as per PeeHaa's suggestions. A is "registered:current" and B is "registered:next". In his testing he is getting the value that comes after A but before B, however in my tests I am only getting the value of A ("registered:current"). It just outputs "registered:current" instead of the value that exists between the 2 markers.

```
function getValuesBetweenMarkers($theArray, $startMarker = 'registered:current', $endMarker = 'registered:next')
{
    $offset = array_search($startMarker, $theArray) + 1;
    $length = array_search($endMarker, $theArray) - $offset;

    return array_slice($theArray, $offset, $length, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Why do you not have 3 separate arrays? Seems more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @Esailija it is more complicated than it needs be. Unfortunately this is how the data is returned from LDAP, I just store it directly into a variable.

Comment: Do you want the indices/keys (`4`, `5`, `6`) or the values (`5`, `6`, `7`) ?

Comment: @salathe Hi sorry for not making that more clear. I want the string values of the indices between A and B, so 5,6,7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$result = array();
$start = "A";
$stop = "B";
$push = false;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($value == $start) {
         $push = true;
    } else if ($value == $stop) {
        break;
    }
    if ($push) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a few of the other ones posted before this one and they didn't work. This one did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
function getValuesBetweenMarkers($theArray, $startMarker = 'A', $endMarker = 'B')
{
    $offset = array_search($startMarker, $theArray) + 1;
    $length = array_search($endMarker, $theArray) - $offset;

    return array_slice($theArray, $offset, $length, true);
}

$array = array('1','2','3','A','5','6','7','B','8','9');
var_dump(getValuesBetweenMarkers($array));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this method, however I am having some issues.. the results output is always one value before the one I want.. so instead of outputting "5, 6, 7", this is just outputting "A" for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to utilize array_search() and array_slice() like this:

```
$index_a = array_search('A', $array);
$index_b = array_search('B', $array);
$offset = $index_a + 1;
$slice_length = $index_b - $offset;

$final_array = array_slice($array, $offset, $slice_length);
```

Of course you would probably want to add more logic to verify both A&B are present as well as to verify they occur in the right order (i.e. that $offset >=0 and that $slice_length > 0)